# Chart balloon not update using updateChart amchart

Tags: angular, typescript, amcharts

I working on updating all chart properties using amcharts angular 5. I changed successfully properties such as backgroundColor ect.. using amChartsService but on working with balloons the balloon color and background color aren't changing. I used to destroy the chart and re-create it, but it's not the best way to do it. I believe that there is a better way to do it there's my code.

```
this.amChartsService.updateChart(this.currentChart, () => {
    this.currentChart['balloon']['color'] = value;
  });
```

on the console.log(this.currentChart.balloon.color); the value already been changed but not in the chart.

Why i'm getting this ? is it a bugg that should be reported or I'm doing something wrong ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in my case below snippet works.

```
function adjustBalloonText(graphDataItem, graph){
   return "something";
}
```

maybe it works!!!

Comment: In the console the propertie value changed but not in the chart that's the issue and i'm using angular 5 typescript.